# Passing variable From UIViewController to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I have tried modify my code many times, but still can't pass variable from UIViewController to UIView, variable always return (null).

//  BPGraphView.h

```
   @interface BPGraphView : UIView

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *test;

    @end
```

//  BPGraphView.m

```
#import "BPGraphView.h"

@implementation BPGraphView
@synthesize test;

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    NSLog(@"test %@",test);

    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{    

    NSLog(@"draw %@", test); // always return (null)

    if ([test isEqual:@"something"])  {
    [self drawOutLine];
    }
}

@end
```

//  BloodPressureViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
BPGraphView * graphview=[[BPGraphView alloc] init];
graphview.test = @"something";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
BPGraphView * graphview=[[BPGraphView alloc] init];
graphview.test = @"dd";
}
```

The variable `graphview` is basically destroyed once the `viewDidLoad` is run to finish. It will never get a chance to run `drawRect`.

Now the question is how should you define a instance variable of `BPGraphView` in your UIViewController. The easiest way should be adding a BPGraphView onto your view's xib file and link to  an IBOutlet in your  UIViewController. In this way, you should be able to assign to test

```
@IBOutlet BPGraphView graphview;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    graphview.test = @"dd";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without setting a frame, drawRect will not be called.

```
BPGraphView * graphview=[[BPGraphView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
graphview.test = @"something";
[self.view addSubview:graphview];
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this,it works well,in your code,drawRect is not called

```
 BPGraphView * graphview=[[BPGraphView alloc] init];
    graphview.test = @"dd";
    [graphview drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```